# React and AppSettings in Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

My goal is to retrieve some environnement keys from Azure Application settings like api_url.

My build factory is the following :

- webpack for the tsx to minified js
- build and release with VSTS
- deploy on Azure Web App

There is no node.js running on Azure Web App, it is just a static server that serve index.html, bundle.js and assets.

I have tried this different method :

1. [Below this example](https://shellmonger.com/2015/09/11/environment-variables-on-azure-app-service/), if I load system vars, I will be able to retrieve this key/value. I have tried with `dotenv-webpack` and systemvars to true but nothing is loaded, obviously I don't have a nodejs server.
2. I've found an url https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings that give me a JSON with all settings, including custom appsettings. So my question is how I can get this, whether in live runtime (this url is protected by account credentials, can I access from web app), or maybe in built process, but in this case, how to access from VSTS ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

To get a JSON with all settings you could send a GET request from your reactjs App to this URL:

```
https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASS@$AZURE_APPNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings
```

The username and password can be found from **Deployment Credentials** in the portal of your App Service:

[image]

Comment: This would expose your deployment credentials to anyone hitting your site.

Comment: this should not be an accepted answer, please don't follow this approach blindly.